# Show mat-table row dynamically after checking a checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to show next steps in my checklist with angular mat-table, after checking the checkbox in the first column.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="checklist.checklistStepList" matSort>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="checked">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Checked</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let step" *ngIf="displayStep(step)"><mat-checkbox [checked]="step.result==='CHECKED'" (change)="updateCheck(step)"></mat-checkbox></td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="step">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Step</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let step" *ngIf="displayStep(step)">{{step.title}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Description</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let step" *ngIf="displayStep(step)">{{step.description}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="owner">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Owner</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let step" *ngIf="displayStep(step)">{{step.owner}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Date</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let step" *ngIf="displayStep(step)">{{step.date}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="assignment">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Assignments</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let step" *ngIf="displayStep(step)">{{step.assignment}}</td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnToDisplay"></tr>
</table>
```

As you can see here, I'm trying to hide/show my checklist steps with the function `displayStep(step)` which is just a function that tells me if the step should be displayed and returns a boolean.

The problem here is that my `step` parameter isn't recognized.

I'm expecting as an output to see the first step, and then after checking it display the next one.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwnnzf

Comment: Provide stackblitz if possible!

Comment: okok hold on good sir :)

Comment: It is not allowed to have two structural directives on the same element.

Comment: Ok it's edited, now you can access the stackblitz. I've simplified some function so it's easy to read.

Comment: I wonder if modifying the datasource isn't the simplest way to do it...

Comment: Do you want to hide the entire row if its unchecked?

Comment: @MA-Moustache Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AjinkyaDhote Yes exactly.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I would like to show the step 2 if the step 1 is checked.  I want to show a step if the previous one is checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide the row for which are not checked you can you something like this

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnToDisplay"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnToDisplay" [hidden]="!row.checked">
</tr>
```

`[hidden]=true`  while hide it

you can see the example [`here`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwnnzf-rm8abh?embed=1&file=app/table-basic-example.html)

Comment: Yeah I upvoted, but as I'm < 15 reputation it doesn't show, it's recorded tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your stackbliz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwnnzf-3p7xvo

explanation:

prepare a steplist on application init.

```
prepareSteps(){
    this.checklistSteps = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < STEPS_MOCK.length ; i++){
      let currStep = STEPS_MOCK[i];

      //push the step to stepList.
      this.checklistSteps.push(currStep);

      //if the last pusded step is not checked then our list is complete so exit the loop
      if(!currStep.checked){
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

then on every checkbox change event update child steps and then prepare the list with updated stpes.

I hope this will help.